# Matlab: Unable to perform inverse operation - How to create non-singular square matrix

Tags: matlab, time-series, covariance, correlation, matrix-inverse

I am trying Matrix operations. The data is a time series model - Autoregressive model, AR(2) where the model order `p =2` represented by the variable `Y` excited by white Gaussian noise, `epsilon`. I am stuck with conceptual questions for which I will be grateful for answers. The code computes the autocorrelation matrix after multiplying the 1 sampled time delayed vector Y with the transpose of the 1 samples time delayed vector. The general formula for correlation is `E(Y*Y')`. In this case I need to do `E(Y(1:end)*Y(1:end)')`. The answer is a scalar if done this way. But, based on  the reply by Walter Roberts [mathematical expectation](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/25441-mathematical-expectation) I am able to get a `9 by 9 matrix`. However, I am not getting a non-singular matrix.

How do I create a singular matrix for the autocorrelation matrix such that the inverse can be computed? Please help

THE CODE:

```
clc;
clear all;
 var_eps = 1;
    epsilon = sqrt(var_eps)*randn(5000,1); % Gaussian signal exciting the AR model

   Y(1) = 0.0;
    Y(2) = 0.0;
    for n= 3:5000
    Y(n)=  0.1950*Y(n-1) -0.9500*Y(n-2)+ epsilon(n); %AR(2) model
    end

  y_tminus1 = Y(1:end-1).';
    mult = y_tminus1*y_tminus1';  %This creates a square matrix
    autocorr = xcorr2(mult);  %To perform autocorrelation of 1 sampled lag time series with itself(1 sampled lag)
  inverse_autocorr = inv(autocorr);  **%PROBLEM**        


%Warning: Matrix is singular to working precision. 
  trace_inv=trace(inverse_autocorr);
```

UPDATE: I am facing this problem since I am trying to implement the terms of the matrix in Expression of Eq(20) and the RHS of Eq(24) [image: img1]
[image: img2]

**UPDATE : 01 Dec**

In this code, the issues, the analytical form of variables

```
CRB_LHS = (b_transpose_b/N)*tr(inv(E[y(t-1)y(t-1)']))

CRB_RHS = sigma2_v*tr(inv(sum_t =1 to N E[y(t-1)y(t-1)']))
```

where **y(t-1)** =

```
[y(t-1), y(t-2),..,y(t-p)]'
```

The CRB_LHS is calculated from Eq(19) of the paper

```
`Y_ARMA(n)=  0.1950*Y_ARMA(n-1)- 0.1950*Y_ARMA(n-2) + b*x_gauss(n);` where

 x_gauss = N(0,1)
```

The CRB_RHS is calculated from Eq(1)

Y_AR(n) =   0.1950*Y_AR(n-1) -0.9500*Y_AR(n-2)  + x_chaos(n);
where

```
x_chaos(n)= f(x(n-1),x(n-2),...,x(n-d)); d = 2
```

I have assumed the coefficients `b = 1` for the white noise in ARMA model of Eq(19).

For each SNR level, `snrbd = -3:1:2` I am simulating `M` number of time series (M independent runs). There are 2 doubts regarding the implementation : (1) for the RHS of Eq(25), in the code the Expectation is taken over the independent runs (according to the suggestion in the answer, provided I understood correctly) - the expression shows that the sum is taken over all the data points & Expectation over M samples for (t-1). This is confusing to implement.
(2) The code throws error due to the inverse. Unable to solve this.

The result should be `CRB_LHS > CRB_RHS` for each snr.

```
clc;
clear all;
N = 10;
M = 100;  % number of independent runs over which the 

  snrdb = -3:1:2;
for snr_levels = 1:length(snrdb)



for monte_carlo = 1: M
     x_gauss = randn(1,N);
     x_chaos(1) = rand();
% generate the chaotic code
    for i =1 : N
        x_chaos(i+1) = 4*x_chaos(i)*(1-x_chaos(i));
    end

    x_chaos = x_chaos-mean(x_chaos);
    Y_AR(1) = 0.0;
    Y_AR(2) = 0.0;

   Y_ARMA(1) = 0.0;
    Y_ARMA(2) = 0.0;
    for n= 3:N
    Y_ARMA(n)=  0.1950*Y_ARMA(n-1)- 0.1950*Y_ARMA(n-2) + x_gauss(n); %Eq(19) model
    Y_AR(n) =   0.1950*Y_AR(n-1) -0.9500*Y_AR(n-2)  + x_chaos(n); %Eq(1)
    end
    % signalPower_Y_AR = var(Y_AR);
 signalPower_Y_AR = 1;

    sigma2_v = signalPower_Y_AR .*(10^(-snrdb(snr_levels))) ;
    v = sqrt(sigma2_v)*randn(1,length(Y_AR));
    z = Y_AR + v;  %Eq(3)

Y_LHS = Y_ARMA(end-2:end-1).';
Y_RHS = z(end-2:end-1).';

A1(:,monte_carlo) = Y_LHS;
B1(monte_carlo,:) = Y_LHS.';

A2(:,monte_carlo) = Y_RHS;
B2(monte_carlo,:) = Y_RHS.';
end


dimension = length(Y_LHS);
sum_of_products_LHS = zeros(dimension,dimension);
sum_prod_RHS = zeros(dimension,dimension);

for runs = 1:M
A = A1(:,runs);
B = B1(runs,:);
mult_LHS = A*B;

C = A2(:,runs);
D = B2(runs,:);
mult_RHS = C*D;

sum_of_products_LHS = sum_of_products_LHS+ mult_LHS;
sum_of_products_RHS = sum_prod_RHS + mult_RHS;
end 

  b_transpose_b = 1;

Expectation_LHS = mean(sum_of_products_LHS);
% Inverse_LHS = inv(Expectation_LHS);
% trace_LHS = tr(Inverse_LHS);

Expectation_RHS = mean(sum_of_products_RHS);

% Inverse_RHS = inv(Expectation_RHS);
% trace_RHS = tr(Inverse_RHS);
%MANUALLY MAKING A SQUARE MATRIX
size_Inverse = 7;
InverseMatrix_LHS = eye(size_Inverse,size_Inverse);
InverseMatrix_RHS = eye(size_Inverse,size_Inverse);

for i = 1:size_Inverse
    InverseMatrix_LHS(i:size_Inverse,i) = Expectation_LHS(1:size_Inverse-i+1);
    InverseMatrix_LHS(i,i:size_Inverse) = Expectation_LHS(1:size_Inverse-i+1);

    InverseMatrix_RHS(i:size_Inverse,i) = Expectation_RHS(1:size_Inverse-i+1);
    InverseMatrix_RHS(i,i:size_Inverse) = Expectation_RHS(1:size_Inverse-i+1);

end
  trace_LHS = tr(InverseMatrix_LHS);
  CRLB_RHS(snr_levels)=  (b_transpose_b/N).*trace_RHS;

  trace_RHS = tr(InverseMatrix_RHS);
  CRLB_RHS(snr_levels)= sigma2_v*trace_RHS;

 end
```

Comment: (Another question in which substantial items of work, including code, were deleted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For p=2, expression for y_tminus1 should be (see expressions after Eq.1 in the paper)

```
y_tminus1 = Y(end-2:end-1).'
```

Your mult is OK. For Eq. 20 you need to take expectation E(mult). For this you need to generate multiple paths and take an average over them. For the RHS of Eq. 25, you need to use y_tminus1 for every step of your ARMA process, sum corresponding mult matrices, take expectation over ensemble and only after that take an inverse. Maybe, try to adjust your code along these lines and i'll correct it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have 2 issues (A) The formula for autocorrelation for lag of 1 sample is E[y(t-1)*y(t-1)']. Is E[y(t-1)*y(t-1)'] equivalent to xcorr2(mult) where mult = y(t-1)*y(t-1)' ? (B) Is there a way to manually make a singular matric non singular?

Comment: Hmm, regarding (A) i'm not sure your expression is correct. Which reference are you using? Regarding (B), you need rank of the matrix be equal to its dimensions, and its det be nonzero. E.g. removing the linearly dependent rows and columns (in your case, corresponding to Y(1) and Y(2)) makes it nonsingular

Comment: I am trying to implement an expression for Cramer Rao bound from paper "Blind identification of AR system sing chaos" IEEE Transactions on Circuits and System. There the Expression of Correlation in the lagged format is presented. I have attached image in my Question for your reference. Could you please have a llok?

Comment: Great! I will implement based on your directions and will let you know here or when I post as a new Question. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, once again. Sorry for late reply I had tough time in figuring out the flow of the code. Yet I am unable to implement it without any error. If the problem has slipped out of your mind (obviously) here is a quick recap. I am trying to implement the analytical expression of Eq(25) given in the paper. I skipped Eq(20) it is way too complicated for me. Eq(25) has two parts - LHS and RHS. Eq(25) shows that the Cramer Rao Lower Bound for ARMA model, where MA part is the Gaussian noise > CRLB for AR model in Eq(1) using deterministic signal expressed by Eq(2).

Comment: I have posted the code in the Question with an explanation of what is going on. I shall be extremely grateful if you can please re-visit the problem and help me out. Thank you for your time & effort.